# Why can't we see better with an antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, radio

Or alternatively: Why don't antennas look like telescopes?

If visible light and radio transmissions are the same thing, why is there such a difference in the equipment we use for augmenting it?

Comment: Because the wavelengths are very different.

Comment: Newtonian telescopes are optical versions of a dish antenna.

Comment: Radio astronomy dishes are very similar to the curved mirrors used in reflecting telescopes, and for the very good reason that they work in the same way. Antennas, as in your TV aerial, aren't dishes because they don't need to form an image - they just measure integrated intensity.

Comment: Compare the design of [Netwonian telescope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newtonian_telescope) and a [radio telescope like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effelsberg_100-m_Radio_Telescope).

Comment: Satellite dishes look like mirror telescopes to me ...

Answer (score 0):

We can see with an antenna, but we need intermediary equipment to convert the radio waves into objects we can sense with our biologically evolved sensory organs.  Here is a link, for example, to an antenna that can focus radio waves to a point: http://news.mit.edu/2012/new-metamaterial-lens-focuses-radio-waves-1114.  With the proper equipment to read the tightly focused radio waves, tiny objects like molecules can be probed and images can be produced.